# Matlab, studying nonlinear systems without simulink

Tags: matlab, linearization

How can I study nonlinear dynamic systems with matlab (and without using Symulink)?

For example, how can I linearize a system around a point or how can I determine the nature of an equilibrium point?

Thanks

---

For example, how can I solve exercise 1 of [this](http://control.lth.se/media/Education/EngineeringProgram/FRTN05/2012/exercises/compendium.pdf)?

Comment: Are you knowledgeable with the mathematics of liniarization etc, or are you just looking for a ready made tool to do that?

Comment: I would prefer a ready made tool, but it is not so important. I just edited the question with a more specific example... I just want use matlab/octave and not simulink. Thanks @nate

Answer (score 2):

You could try one of the stiff solvers such as `ode23s` or `ode23tb Here's another [link](http://jitkomut.lecturer.eng.chula.ac.th/matlab/dynamics.html) that might be helpful...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I know how to solve nonlinear systems. But how to determine the nature of the zeros of dynamic nonlinear systems?